# Replying to a message with a embed (Discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

i'm having a problem where i can't reply to a message with an embed.
is this even possible? I'm guessing it is and im just doing it horribly wrong.

My error - TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression

```
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
       await message.reply
       embedVar = discord.Embed(description=".order", color=0x7289da)       
       embedVar.add_field(name='test', value='test')
       await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [`discord.py` API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html), it should be possible. Note that [`Message.reply()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.reply) is a method, not an attribute. The documentation describes the method:

> A shortcut method to `abc.Messageable.send()` to reply to the Message.

The method takes positional argument `content` and keywords arguments `kwargs`, which correspond to the keyword arguments of the [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) method. Since `embed` is one of the keyword arguments, it is one of `reply()` as well.

```py
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=".order", color=0x7289da)
    embed.add_field(name="test", value="test")
    await message.reply(embed)
```

On a side note, I suggest using the `discord.ext.commands` framework instead of using `on_message()` and string methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the [`reply`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reply#discord.Message.reply) function correctly. You cannot have it by itself, as you have done with `await message.reply` in your code.

```py
# on_message event, the way you have done it
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    await message.reply("This is a test!")

# or if you prefer the commands extension (recommended)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("This is a test!")
# you can also make it so it doesn't mention the author
    await ctx.reply("This is a test!", mention_author=False)

# Note that both of the code in the commands example can be used in your on_message event
# as long as you remember to change ctx to message
```

The above code has been tested as seen in the image below.

[image: Code working]

---

As for replying with embeds, I have found that if the bot is only replying with an embed, it may not mention the author.

```py
    embed = discord.Embed(description="This is a test", color=0x123456)
    await message.reply(embed=embed)
```

The above code works as seen in the image below.

[image: code above working]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

embed=discord.Embed(title="Tile",

```
description="Desc", color=0x00ff00) 

embed.add_field(name="Fiel1", value="hi", inline=False)

embed.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
```

`